# Cannot Add Hidden Network Before Installing Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install the Ubuntu 19.10. I cannot find the "add hidden network" at the beginning of the installation.

How do I setup the wi-fi so I can download while installing the system?

Comment: Should I install Ubuntu then update? Or downloading while installing? Which way is better?

Comment: Choose "Try Ubuntu", setup the hidden network, then "install". Or Choose "Try Ubuntu", setup the hidden network, quit, reboot, Choose "Install  Ubuntu" and install? Which way is better?

Comment: I'm confused. If I choose "Try Ubuntu", and setup hidden network, then quit, reboot, and choose"Install Ubuntu", will the hidden network be remembered? Or the hidden network be lost?

Comment: What's the difference between the two options? "Try Ubuntu", connect network, install from the Desktop, does the installer installs the os, then installs the downloaded files? Does the "Install Ubuntu", installs the os, then connect network, download the updates, and install the files? If so, then two options are basically the same.

Comment: Install from "Try Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu", which is better?

Comment: Will a "wired connection" work with the Install Ubuntu?

Comment: yes, it works..

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no option to choose wifi settings while installing ubuntu from "install ubuntu" menu
[image]

you can quit the process which will automatically take you to "try ubuntu" mode.
[image]

then choose the wifi settings and configure your hidden network.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Alternatively you can directly choose "Try Ubuntu" option while booting the live ISO
[image]

[image]